# iOS and unicode characters: \u+2605 not solid star in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, uilabel

I'm trying to make a UILabel that says "★ FEATURED". However, when it renders it, the star isn't solid! Here's the code I'm using:

```
    _sponsoredLabel = [UILabel new];
    _sponsoredLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    _sponsoredLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    _sponsoredLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    _sponsoredLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _sponsoredLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    _sponsoredLabel.text = @"✭ FEATURED";
    _sponsoredLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:14.0f];
    _sponsoredLabel.hidden = YES;
```

In the text itself it looks solid, but here's what it looks like when it renders: [image]

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: that's curious, have you tried using @"\u2605 FEATURED" to see if something is different about the one you put in?

Comment: I'l make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your literal character is not `\u2605`. It is `\u272D` - Outlined Black Star. You typed the wrong character when you typed your literal.

Answer (score 2):

Different fonts represent glyphs differently - that's what a font *is*. If you don't like the way HeveticaNeue-Light represents this glyph, find a font that represents it in a way that you *do* like.

Comment: For example, try an Arial or a Heiti font.

Comment: Turns out I needed to use the actual unicode value, rather than the character itself.

Comment: @Mason No, that makes no sense. You were typing the wrong character when you typed that character. In other words, the star in your literal text is _not_ `\u2605`.

Answer (score 1):

That's curious, have you tried using @"\u2605 FEATURED" to see if something is different about the one you put in?

Unicode characters have names and 2605 is "Black Star." (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2605/index.htm) so there's a decent chance you've just type something else in your code.